# How to query specific model in TDB?

Tags: sparql, jena

I built one TDB dataset with many named models,and all of these models contain  large amounts of data.I know that I can get the specific model from TDB dataset,and then query against to this model,but in this way,large memory is needed.

With this :select ?s ?p ?o where {graph ?g {?s ?p ?o}.},I can query all named models data out.Is there any way to query the specific one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply replace `?g` with the URI of the named model e.g.

```
SELECT * WHERE
{
  GRAPH <http://example.org/graph>
  { ?s ?p ?o }
}
```

The other alternative is to leave `?g` in place and instead add some `FROM NAMED` clauses to the query which restrict the named graphs considered by `GRAPH` clauses  e.g.

```
SELECT
FROM NAMED <http://graph/1>
FROM NAMED <http://graph/2>
WHERE
{
  GRAPH ?g { ?s ?p ?o }
}
```

Comment: Finally I sloved this problem,the models' name should be URI,not just String